# Count the numbers of equal rows in a file

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

Suppose you have a file.dat of the form:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
...
```

I want to count how many equal numbers there are and save them iteratively in a string. For instance:

```
m = 3 (times 1),
m = 2 (times 2),
m = 4 (times 3).
```

I put here my code:

```
    program sele
        implicit none
        integer::j,k,s,n,l,r,m
        real*8,allocatable::ID(:)
        real*8:: j_r8,i_r8

        open(10,file='data.dat')
        n=0
            DO
              READ(10,*,END=100)
              n=n+1
            END DO

     100     continue
            rewind(10)

        allocate(ID(n))
    s=0
        do s=1, n
            read(10,*) ID(s)
        end do

    do r=1,n-1
    if (ID(r)-ID(r+1) .EQ. 0) then
    m = m + 1
    print*, m
     end if
    end do

   end program
```

The last `do` is the condition I'd like to expand, with something like:

```
 if (condition is true) then
  save an index of the number of equal digits
  use this to do some operations:
```

do i = 1, number of equal digits
     if (condition is not true) then
      restart with the other digits.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm forming the view that you are trying to learn Fortran entirely by Q&A here on SO.  I think, for your own benefit, that you should be trying a lot harder to solve your own problems.  This, for example, is a very simple problem.  Kick away the crutch and walk.  I, for one, won't be helping you any more.

Comment: As with your other question today you don't really have a Fortran problem, but an algorithm problem.  I think it's good you are trying to learn Fortran (even here, where it isn't necessarily the most efficient too), but I think you should also work on the _programming_ side of things too.  By which I mean: "what am I trying to do?" along with "how do I do it in Fortran?".

Answer (score 0):

If the values you want to read are integer values in a given limited range (for instance from 1 to 100), then the simplest way is the following :

```
program sele
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: vmin=1
   integer, parameter :: vmax=100
   integer            :: list(vmin:vmax) 
   integer            :: value,i       
   open(10,file='data.dat')
   list=0
   do
      read(10,*,end=10) value
      if(value < vmin .OR. value > vmax) then
         write(*,*) 'invalid value ',value
         stop
      endif
      list(value)=list(value)+1
   enddo
10 continue
   do i=vmin,vmax
     if(list(i) > 0) then
        write(*,*) list(i),' times ',i
     endif
   enddo
end program
```

Which gives on your example :

```
3 times 1
2 times 2
4 times 3
```

It is possible to improve easily that program to manage variable vmin and vmax (the array list must then be declared allocatable and allocated at the right size). 
If the range is too large, then a simple array is not accurate anymore and the  right algorithm becomes more complicated : it must avoid to store unused values.